# Anchor a div to another div that's not in the same tree

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog

I have a pretty complex modal in which my users can dynamically add rows (== options) in which there are multiple `select` elements. These `select`'s open customized dropdown menus with the different options.

**The problem I'm facing:**

1 - a user adds enough options to make the containing div overflow, and it becomes necessary to scroll through all the rows but always within the modal

2 - the user clicks on a `select` input, which opens the options' dropdown

3 - the user somehow scrolls through the rows

**Expected:**

The options' dropdown remains anchored to the `select` input

**Actual:**

The dropdown keeps its 'absolute' position relative to the modal, meaning that it appears to scroll along with the rest of the div, floating above the other rows.

The input is in a form contained in the modal, while the select dropdown is at the very bottom of the page:

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <div id="modal">
      <form>
        <input type='select' id="my-select">
        </input>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
   <!-- Dropdown attached to #my-select -->
   <div id="dropdown">
     <div>First option</div>
   </div>
  </div>      
</body>
```

I'm guessing there's no easy way to achieve what I want with only css? If that is the case, what kind of JS sorcery would be needed?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: @SandeshGupta It's several hundred lines of React and SCSS code, third party libraries etc, so I guess what I need is a conceptual answer more than actual code...